# discord.js ERR args

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I've coded a mute command but I have a Error. But I can`t fix the Error. Im not sure I tried every possible way for me to fix this problem. But I stuck there xD

Code:

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js")
const botconfig = require("../botconfig.json");
const colours = require("../colours.json");
const superagent = require("superagent")

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
    message.delete();
    const args = message.content.slice(6).split(" ");
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply("Dazu hast du keine Rechte!")

    let tomute = message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1]);
    if (message.author.id == tomute.id) return message.reply("Du kannst dich nicht selbst muten!");
    if (!tomute) return message.reply("Konnte den User nicht finden..");
    let extracounter = 1
    let mutetime = args[2];
    if (!mutetime) return message.reply("Keine Zeit angegeben..");
    let mutetimez = args[3];
    if (!mutetimez) return message.reply("Kein Zeitformat angegeben..")
    if (mutetimez === "m") extracounter = 60000;
    if (mutetimez === "h") extracounter = 360000;
    if (mutetimez === "s") { extracounter = 1000; }

    await message.guild.members.cache.get(tomute.id).roles.add("796635469348995113");

    await message.reply(`<@${tomute.id}> wurde für ${mutetime} ${mutetimez} gemuted!`);

    setTimeout(async function() {
        await message.guild.members.cache.get(tomute.id).roles.remove("796635469348995113");
        message.channel.send(`<@${tomute.id} wurde nach ${(mutetime)} ${(mutetimez)} entmuted!`);
    }, mutetime * extracounter)
    return;
}

module.exports.config = {
    name: "mute",
    description: "Bans a user from the guild!",
    usage: "+ban",
    accessableby: "Administrators",
    aliases: ["chatmute"]
}
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Replaysucht.de\discord\Bot\commands\tempmute.js:8
    const args = message.content.slice(6).split(" ");
          ^

SyntaxError: Identifier 'args' has already been declared
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Replaysucht.de\discord\Bot\index.js:26:20
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Replaysucht.de\discord\Bot\index.js:25:12
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

Im just confused because of the error. Never excepted that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already have defined args in "`async(bot, message, args)`" which you cant define it again in "`const args = message.content.slice(6).split(" ");`" thats what that err tells you.